# 2007 Ford f150 unlock/lock button

Tags: ford, locks, f-150, central-locking

I have not had this truck long I bought it  a couple of weeks ago and the driver side unlock buttons work for the driver side only but the lock button works for both sides. I can only unlock the passenger side from that side of the truck using those buttons. And I need to know how to fix this

Comment: This sounds like normal/desired behaviour. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Some vehicle press twice quickly on driver side and it will unlock passenger also